# why libpcap cannot capture outbound 802.11 beacons?

Tags: linux-kernel, wifi, libpcap, packet-capture, tcpdump

I am writing my own program, which will be running on a 802.11 AP, to capture all the outgoing beacons on the AP. But I just noticed I cannot do it with the current libpcap: the program couldn't capture any outbound beacons. I've also tried Wireshark which gave the same result.

My questions are:

1. Can anyone shed some lights on the causes of what I saw?
2. Is there any user space method that I can capture the outbound beacons of a 802.11 AP on that specific AP (rather than capturing on other PCs)? It is better for me if I can do this without hacking into the wireless driver.

I am using Ubuntu 10.04 as the OS, Madwifi as the wireless driver.

Thanks, folks.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that the WiFi chip is generating the beacons autonomously
so they never pass the driver-chip interface where libpcap intercepts
packets. You'll probably need a second radio to be able to capture the
beacons from the air (when the primary radio is busy sending a beacon
the receiver is turned off so it can't hear what it is transmitting).

Answer (score 0):

You can Capture those packets(Beacon ,Acknowledgement,etc) in wireshark
all you need to do is following :

> 1. go to capture menu
> 2. after selecting your interface go to option
> 3. select the per packet information option in link layer type of your interface
>
> press start